# I was trying out aggregation pipeline operation in springdata mongodb with kotlin, I am facing issue with projection operation stage

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, spring-data-mongodb

I have to use projection operation to apply conditionaloperators ifNull in my operation on two fields ie sourceId and applicationId, the code is something like this -

```
 return Aggregation.project()
            .and(ifNull("\$applicationId")
            .thenValueOf("\$sourceId"))
            .`as`("caseIdKey")
            .andInclude("\$\$ROOT")
```

I am of the opinion that andInclude will help me to output all the fields in my document but in my unit test I am getting a 500 internal server error.

I tried out andInclude & .andArrayOf("$$ROOT"), this appends the root fields but that it does inside an node ie task:[root fields], how can I try to resolve this or if project is not the right place to have this how can I have ifNull implemented on the group operation.

**Additional question - Can I apply ifNull in group stage in aggregation pipeline something like -
Aggregation.group(ifNull("$applicationId").thenValueof("$sourceId")**

Comment: got a solution to above approach by using addFields, where we introduced a new field based on conditionalOperators (ifNull), which resolved the issue of fields being mishandled or nested inside a different node.